# Dbfit standalone mode in Fitnesse.NET/fitsharp not working for me

Tags: .net, fitnesse, fitsharp, dbfit

In attempting to upgrade to the latest Fitnesse/fitSharp release for .NET I find that my database actions, written in standalone mode, now fail uniformly. This worked fine with my older Fitnesse installation (without fitSharp). This attempt to connect to a database:

```
!|import      |
|dbfit.fixture|

!|DatabaseEnvironment|sqlserver|
|Connect|Data Source=DevDB1;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI|
```

generates this error:

```
fitSharp.Machine.Exception.TypeMissingException: Type 'SqlServerEnvironment' not found in assemblies:
<assemblies listed here>. . .
```

The list of searched assemblies includes dbfit.DLL, dbfit.Oracle.DLL, and dbfit.SqlServer.DLL, and .NET Reflector confirms that 'SqlServerEnvironment' is in fact in the dbfit.DLL file.

If I change from **standalone mode** to **flow mode**, with the following test table as the first table in the test, then the DB connection works fine:

```
!|dbfit.SqlServerTest                                                      |
|Connect|Data Source=DevDB1;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI|
```

**Version info:**

- Fitnesse.jar is version 20110104
- fitSharp is version 1.8 for .net 4.0
- OS: WinXP Pro SP3

Am I missing something or is this a known defect in the latest version of fitSharp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug. Should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Any idea when the next release is due?

Comment: Depends on my free time. Hopefully end of this month.